# Change theme based on window size

Tags: ajax, responsive

I want to send a browser info (window width) to the server via AJAX. The server doesn't need to respond with any data, however, only change the theme based on that window width.

This is my attempt:

**javascript**

```
var $ = jQuery;

$(document).ready(function() {

    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url: ".../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      data: {
        action: 'ajax_action',
        windowWidth: windowWidth,
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        alert('success ' + data); // might not be useful.
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
      }
   });

});
```

**functions.php**

```
function mmf_enqueue_scripts() {
  if( !is_admin() ):
    wp_enqueue_script('winsize-detect');
  endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'mmf_enqueue_scripts' );


function ajax_action() {

  if( isset( $_POST['windowWidth'] ) ) {
    return $_POST['windowWidth'];
  }

  return 0;

}


function mmf_change_theme($theme) {

  // to make AJAX run only before this function
  add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_action', 'ajax_action');
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_action', 'ajax_action');


  $width = ajax_action();
  if( $width == 320 ) {
    $theme = 'twentytwelve';
    // if I echo the width here I get: 3203203203200 (if width=320)
  }
  else {
    $theme = 'twentythirteen';
    // if I echo the width here I get: 7707707707700 (if width=770)
  }

  return $theme;
}

add_filter('template', 'mmf_change_theme');
add_filter('option_template', 'mmf_change_theme');
add_filter('option_stylesheet', 'mmf_change_theme');
```

I am having hard time dealing with the fact that function `mmf_change_theme` is hooked, so it is called 3 times. Or I am analyzing wrongly.

How would you do it? Or how to correct my code.
Also you feedback on such a method to serve different themes based on window browser size is appreciated.

I prefer not to use a plugin, which exist I know.

Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask why you're trying to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

Your code actually works for me and it is changing the theme according to the current width.

But I think you should need some tweaking something like below:

For your JavaScript:

```
var $ = jQuery;

$(document).ready(function() {

    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", // Must use absolute url
      data: {
        action: 'ajax_action',
        windowWidth: windowWidth,
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        alert('success ' + data); // might not be useful.
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
      }
   });

});
```

Use absolute URL, sometimes it won't find the `admin-ajax.php` file, because of incorrect handling of the relative URL.

For `functions.php`

```
function mmf_enqueue_scripts() {
  if( !is_admin() ):
    wp_enqueue_script('winsize-detect');
  endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mmf_enqueue_scripts' ); // Use `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead of `wp_print_scripts`

function ajax_action() {

    if( isset( $_POST['windowWidth'] ) ) {
        return $_POST['windowWidth'];
    }
    return 0;
}


function mmf_change_theme($theme) {

  // to make AJAX run only before this function
  add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_action', 'ajax_action');
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_action', 'ajax_action');


  $width = ajax_action();
  //use '<='
  // This might be your mistake, it worked for me.

  if( $width <= 320 ) {  
    $theme = 'twentytwelve';
    // if I echo the width here I get: 3203203203200 (if width=320)
  }
  else {
    $theme = 'twentyteleven';
    // if I echo the width here I get: 7707707707700 (if width=770)
  }

  return $theme;
}

add_filter('template', 'mmf_change_theme');
add_filter('option_template', 'mmf_change_theme');
add_filter('option_stylesheet', 'mmf_change_theme');
```

Don't use `wp_print_scripts` because its not recommended. Use `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead.

Make sure don't equal it to specific width, try less than or equal to `<=`.

Replace `==` with `<=`

Comment: About the absolute url, I am using it already, but in the post I intentionally used 3 dots not to show the domain.
If it works using '<=' then there is something suspicious to me. It might not be doing the right comparison with the right value.
Thanks for your help. I hoped more people to be interested.